# Factorial Series Written As Recursive Definition

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factorial, recursion, recursive-algorithms

I have a factorial series as shown below:

\begin{equation}
(2n+1)!~\text{for all $n \geq 0$}
\end{equation}

And I would like to know if the recursive definition that I wrote is accurate:

\begin{equation}
  Factorial(n)=\begin{cases}
    n, & \text{if $n<0$}.\\
    (2n+1)\cdot Factorial((2n+1)-1), & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Can anybody verify if I have done this correctly? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are wrong. It should be $Factorial(n)=(2n+1)(2n)Factorial(n-1)$ for the $n\geq 0 $ case. $Factorial((2n+1)-1)$ is so much larger than $Factorial(n)$ and you cannot use different definition for your factorial function. You need to be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

If you take $Factorial(n)$ for $n \geq 0$ according to the definition, this will be defined as:

$Factorial(n) = (2n+1)Factorial(2n) = (2n+1)(4n+1)Factorial(4n) = (2n+1)(4n+1)(8n+1)Factorial(8n) = \ldots$

I think what you may be looking for instead is:

$Factorial(n) = (2n+1)(2n)Factorial(n-1)$

Also, you may want to specify what $Factorial(n)$ is for some small values of $n$, since otherwise it's not clear what $Factorial(0)$ is for example.

Comment: Do you know why that implementation in Java would output 0?`static int fact(int n) {
       if(n < 0)
         return n;

       return (2*n+1)*(2*n)*fact(n-1);
    }`

Comment: @Nic When $n$ is $0$, you returned $0$, so when $n$ is positive, it uses the case of $n-1$ as a factor of the answer.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know much Java, but I think once the recursion gets to $n=0$, the next step is to replace $Factorial(0)$ by $(2n+1)(2n)Factorial(-1) = (1)(0)(-1)$, which will cause the product to equal $0$.

Comment: @Element118 I don't think I am returning 0 in my code. What do you mean?

Comment: @Nic Factorial(5)=11*10*Factorial(4)=11*10*9*8*Factorial(3)=11*10*9*8*7*6*Factorial(2)=11*10*9*8*7*6*5*4*Factorial(1)=11*10*9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2*Factorial(0)=11*10*9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1*0*Factorial(-1)=0